# Freeing a port after client disconnects with mqtt broker

Tags: c, client, mosquitto, broker, apollo

I am using an apollo broker and mosquitto C client library. After successfully publishing the message I disconnect the client using the mosquitto_disconnect(mosq) function. but it looks like the port that the client used to connect with the broker is still not free. Is there any way to manually free the port that the client used to connect with the broker in a c program?

```
void on_publish(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int mid)
{

    mosquitto_disconnect(mosq);

    log_print("mqtt",1,"Inside publish callback");


}

int sendData_mqtt(char *address, char *port, char* url, char *data)
{
    struct mosquitto *mosq;
    int err; 
    char *clean_session = "true";
    char *retain_flag = "true";
    int port1= atoi(port);

    mosq = mosquitto_new("unknown", clean_session, NULL);
    mosquitto_publish_callback_set(mosq, on_publish);

    mosquitto_username_pw_set(mosq,"admin","password"); 
    err=mosquitto_connect(mosq, address,port1,60);
    if(err != 0 ){
        log_print("mqtt",1,"connect error= %s\n",mosquitto_strerror(err));
        return -1;
    }
        else 
            log_print("mqtt",1,"successfully connected");
    err = mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "subject", strlen(data), data, 1, retain_flag);

    sleep(5);
    if(err != 0 ) {
        log_print("mqtt",1,"Publish error = %s\n",mosquitto_strerror(err));
        return -1;
        }   
    mosquitto_loop_forever(mosq,-1,1); 

    return 10;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should happen automatically, once libmosquitto thinks it has sent the DISCONNECT packet it will close the socket.

Have you called mosquitto_loop_forever() or mosquitto_loop_start() in order to have the network traffic be processed?

What version of libmosquitto are you using?

Could it be that the broker is rejecting your credentials without you realising? Try adding a log callback to see what is happening.

```
void on_log(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int level, const char *msg)
{
    printf("%s\n", msg);
}
```

And use

```
mosquitto_log_callback_set(mosq, on_log);
```

I'm tempted to say that you need to go back to basics as well. Look at the clean_session and retain arguments to mosquitto_new and mosquitto_publish - they shouldn't be a `char *` string set to "true". Read the documentation, see what tools are available for you to do debugging (e.g. on_log) then get out and do some debugging. Maybe look through the source to see what you would expect to happen.

Comment: I used mosquitto_loop_forever() and libmosquitto Version 1.4.2

Comment: actually its the same code that you instructed to use in of my earlier question, but anyway ill add the code